# Function result type derived from param without casting

Tags: typescript

In the following code:

```js
function fourtyTwo<T extends boolean>(num: T): T extends true ? number : string {
    if (num) {
        return 42;
    } else {
        return 'fourty-two';
    }
}
```

I get 2 instances of the same error:

1. `Type '42' is not assignable to type 'T extends true ? number : string'.ts(2322)`
2. `Type '"fourty-two"' is not assignable to type 'T extends true ? number : string'.ts(2322)`

Is there a way to get this working without casting the return type?

Comment: I had searched for similar but I couldn't find that, thanks!
Looking its answers, I think the answer for my question is "no".